# Synapse Spark using single executor during the write operation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

I am running a Spark job on Azure Synapse using a notebook. I have configured the Spark cluster with 239 executors, 4 vCores each (956 vCores total).

I have a dataframe which I am writing to an Azure storage account as follows:

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader","false")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",1912)

readDf = spark.read.parquet(srcPath)
print(readDf.rdd.getNumPartitions()) # output: 2169

# df = some join, groupby, select, etc. operations on readDf with other dataframes.

print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions()) # output: 6
df.repartition(956).write.mode('overwrite').parquet(path)
```

During the write operation, the Spark is using only one executor:[image]

The output of the first print statement with number of partitions is, `2169` whereas output of second partition count statement is `6`. I am unable to identify how the joins or other operations led to reduced partition size of the dataframe? The original dataframe is joined and operated with other smaller dataframes of lesser partitions, but then `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` should have maintained the partition count after the operation, based on my understanding.

Now, because of less partitions before write, with or without the `repartition` clause, the write operation is taking lot of time and only one executor is performing the task.

Any pointers here would be really helpful!